# jQueryUI Drop & Revert

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, droppable

I want to have it so that when I drag a draggable object (a) onto a droppable object (b), the drop event for b is triggered and a is reverted to its original position.  Is this possible?

```
b.droppable({
    drop:function(event,ui){
        ui.draggable.revert <---- REVERT THE DRAGGABLE OBJECT TO ORIGINAL POSITION HERE
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sTD8y/1/) to have an idea of what you want to achieve.

It sets the revert function you want:

```
$(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable({ 
        revert:  function(dropped) {
           var dropped = dropped && dropped[0].id == "droppable";
           if(!dropped) alert("I'm reverting!");
           return !dropped;
        } 
    }).each(function() {
        var top = $(this).position().top;
        var left = $(this).position().left;
        $(this).data('orgTop', top);
        $(this).data('orgLeft', left);
    });

    $("#droppable").droppable({
        activeClass: 'ui-state-hover',
        hoverClass: 'ui-state-active',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight').find('p').html('Dropped!');
        },
        out: function(event, ui) {
            ui.draggable.mouseup(function () {
                var top = ui.draggable.data('orgTop');
                var left = ui.draggable.data('orgLeft');
                ui.position = { top: top, left: left };
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I was hoping to revert on drop.  not revert on a failed drop